# Multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 2D array from the data read from .txt file.
The data in 'data.txt' look like belows:

```
A;B;4
A;C;5
B;C;8
```

Assume it is symmetry.
Is there any way to create a 2D matrix [i][j] and print in d[i][j] = value?

Appreciate your comments/suggestion.

Comment: you can create char array and store value and key there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2D arrays are useful when the dimensions are known at compile time. If this is the case, other answers can be useful. If not, a 2D array isn't for you.

I suggest using a simple 1D array, allocated (`malloc`) to have n*n entries.
Then, to access cell i/j, use `array[i*n+j]`.

Another approach is to allocate an array of pointers to arrays. Creating it is more complicated, but you can access it as `array[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int tda[3][3];
tda[1][2] = 'x';
```

You can also use malloc for a dynamically-sized array.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 4

int main(int argc, char **args) {
    int A[N][N], i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0 ; j < N; j++)
            A[i][j] = i + j;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: It just sets some values in a 4x4 matrix and then prints them.